# Loading raw res not only at first runtime

Tags: android, dictionary, resources, runtime

I am trying to change the code of the Searchable Dictionary example (full code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm)), so that I can modify "description.txt" and it will update it when I build the program from Eclipse to my application.

I think it doesn't take the modifications into account after the first time because the dictionary is already loaded, with this function:

```
    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Anybody knows how to change this, so that it always load the new "definition.txt" and that I can keep modifying it without having to reinstall the app all the time?

Comment: even with the original code the purpose is not fulfilled instantaneously; I don't get the whole list loaded. If anybody can indicate me which kind of literature to read up on to try and solve myself this problem...

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to achieve - simply changing and recompiling your code should work for you - IF you want to change the dictionary at RUNTIME then you are on completely the wrong track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific code, the solution was to increment the database version in DictionaryDatabase.java:

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;